# Unable to print numbers entered into an array in reverse order

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, reverse

I'm attempting to write a program with an array in which:

- The user enters 10 integers, and the integers are then displayed in reverse order, or
- The user enters up to 10 integers and exits the while-loop using a 0, and the integers entered are then displayed in reverse order.

The code below is my best effort (my 5th attempt at solving the problem), but it's collecting the integer zero and displaying it in the array index (I've attempted to attach the other five, but it keeps producing an error):

[image]

```
int main()
{
   #define ARRAY_LENGTH 10

   int numbers[ARRAY_LENGTH];
   int numbersEntered = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
   {
       numbers[i] = 0;
   }

   int number = 0;
   printf("Enter an integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
   scanf_s("%d", &number);

   while (number != 0 && numbersEntered < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1)
   {
       numbersEntered++; 
       numbers[numbersEntered] = number;
       printf("Enter another integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
       scanf_s("%d", &number);
   }

   for (int i = numbersEntered; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       printf("index %d -> %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You skip the first element of the array in your `while` loop because you increment `numbersEntered` before you write. You need to switch the order

Comment: Unrelated, both of those prompt printf's are passing an argument that isn't called for (there is no specifier in the format string, so passing `ARRAY_LENGTH-1` afterward make no sense).

Comment: You can initialize all elements in the array to zero by int numbers[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {0}; note this only works when initializing to zero.

Comment: Thank your comments. They're all really helpful. @WhozCraig - my instructor recommended the code ARRAY_LENGTH-1, but I can see from removing it and trying it out that it's superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem is first you're initializing the entire array with zero here

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
   {
   numbers[i] = 0;
   }
```

Then you're doing this

```
while (number != 0 && numbersEntered < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1)
   {
   numbersEntered++; 
   numbers[numbersEntered] = number;
   printf("Enter another integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
   scanf_s("%d", &number);
   }
```

So what is happening is, since **numbersEntered** was already initialized with zero you're incrementing it by 1, so the first digit is entered in the array **numbers** is 0 as you initialized the entire array itself in the start.

So a quick fix would be just to move it a line down and change the while loop code to this

```
while (number != 0 && numbersEntered < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1)
   {
   numbers[numbersEntered] = number;
   numbersEntered++; 
   printf("Enter another integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
   scanf_s("%d", &number);
   }
```

Also as pointed out by Kiran in the comments, the printing for loop needs to be changed to this

```
for (int i = numbersEntered-1; i > 0; i--)
   {
   printf("index %d -> %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
   }
```

Comment: And what about the `for` loop one which is used for printing array elements, Is it fine?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and your explanation. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not inserting any number to the first place in the array (place[0]), because you are prompting the value of `numbersEntered` too early. Try to write your loop this way:

```
while (number != 0 && numbersEntered < ARRAY_LENGTH - 1){
   numbers[numbersEntered] = number;
   printf("Enter another integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);
   scanf_s("%d", &number);
   numbersEntered++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The line 
   `printf("Enter an integer; 0 to quit: ", ARRAY_LENGTH - 1);` should be 
   `printf("Enter an integer; 0 to quit: ");`
2. You should use `scanf` not `scanf_s`

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10

int main()
{
    int numbers[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int i;
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k != ARRAY_LENGTH; ++k)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer; 0 to quit: ");
        if (scanf("%d", numbers + k) != 1 || numbers[k] == 0)
            break;
    }

    for (i = k - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        printf("index %d -> %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This here is a solution of mine which includes some good practices, that is a tweak of your code:

1) you would want your defines outside of a function (or main) so that you can use the same constant in the entire program;

2) any function that has a return type (e.g int main) must return something at the end, thus you must have a "return 0" at the end of your main function;

3) the do-while part will ensure that your piece of code will be executed once before the while condition is checked;

4) `numbers[numbersEntered++] = number;` will assign to "numbers[numbersEntered]" the value of "number" and then will increment "numbersEntered" by one; This is to reduce the amount of code that you have to write :);

Hope this helped, and if you have more questions, I hope I can answer them :).

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 10

int main()
{

    int numbers[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int numbersEntered = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
        numbers[i] = 0;

    int number = 0;

    do
    {

        printf("Enter an integer; 0 to quit: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number);

        if (number == 0)
            break;

        numbers[numbersEntered++] = number;


    } while (number != 0 && numbersEntered < ARRAY_LENGTH);

    if (numbersEntered > 0)
    {

        for (int i = numbersEntered - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            printf("index %d -> %d\n", i, numbers[i]);

    }

    return 0;

}
```